# Word similar to 'insidious' or 'pernicious', with a non-negative connotation

Tags: single-word-requests

I'm looking to describe an effect caused by using a particular construction in English, and the fact that it affects the listener and the whole of their thought processes without the listener being aware of it. The words *insidious* or *pernicious* would almost do, but these have negative connotations. The effect here is neither positive or negative.

> The use of (x) has a(n) _____ effect on our mental processes.

That sentence requires an adjective, but an adverb would do just as well :

> The use of (x)  affects our mental processes _____ .

So, a quick recap. Ideally the word would:

- convey that the process is silent and unnoticed by the speaker
- convey that it spreads through and affects all of the speaker's thought processes
- not have any particularly negative or positive connotation

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84552/discussion-on-question-by-araucaria-word-similar-to-insidious-or-pernicious).

Answer (score 32):

A stimulus that is below the threshold of conscious perception, but nevertheless influences one’s mental processes is said to be **subliminal**, or to influence them **subliminally**. As the OP requested, characterising some influence on a person as subliminal, does not imply anything as to whether the influence, or the motivation for it, is good, bad, or neutral. The [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subliminal_stimuli) on the topic provides a serviceable explanation of the concept. The term started out as a technical term of psychology, but quite a few people have by now heard at least some popular outline of this phenomenon to be able to understand the term. In informal speaking and writing, the term is often used more loosely than among professional psychologists.

Comment: -1 *Subliminal* simply stands for "below the threshold of conscious perception" -- the rest of the story is our imagination.

Answer (score 31):

**subtle**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/subtle)

> a. So slight as to be difficult to detect or describe; elusive: a subtle smile.
>
> b. Difficult to understand; abstruse:

As in:

The use of (x) has a **subtle** effect on our mental processes.

Comment: I don't know whether this is unique enough to merit its own answer, but in this case, I'd personally lean towards using the word "subtle" alongside an explicitly positive word. For example, "the use of (x) subtly benefits our mental processes" or "the use of (x) has a subtle, positive effect on our mental processes". Ad any rate, +1

Comment: I don't think there's a better single word answer.

Answer (score 14):

**[Permeating](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/permeate)**:

to pass into or through every part of

to be diffused through; pervade; saturate

Comment: Sad it's closed, there a a lot of good answers. I'd suggest considering "systemic".

Answer (score 12):

In this particular context, I would use [***subconscious***](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/subconscious)<sup>1</sup>. From Oxford Dictionaries:

> Of or concerning the part of the mind of which one is not fully aware but which influences one's actions and feelings.

This is a fairly neutral term, and captures the sense of affecting thought processes without the thinker's conscious awareness. It would work adverbially, as well, so you could say either

> The use of (x) has a **subconscious** effect on our mental processes.

Or

> The use of (x) **subconsciously** affects on our mental processes.

If those don't sound strong enough, you could add a modifier (and could potentially drop the phrase "mental processes, since that is implied in the term) for something like

> The use of (x) has **various/widespread/pervasive subconscious** effects.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Or *unconscious* if you want to be consistent with technical psychoanalytic terminology. However, in a lay setting I think *subconscious* is at least as common.</sub>

Answer (score 11):

**Pervasive/Pervasively** (meaning, permeates through everything, from Latin "passed through") can and usually does have negative connotations, but does not necessarily have to. https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/pervasive lists "A pervasive rhythm" and "A pervasive sense of calm" as being valid.

**Ubiquitous** (meaning "present everywhere", from Latin for "everywhere") has the connotations more of something which is everyday and utilitarian to the point of being ubiquitous. However, it doesn't work so well in the OP's example sentences.

Answer (score 5):

Could I perhaps venture ***surreptitious***? Perhaps, again too negative. Its synonyms are given as things like *covert*, *sneaky* etc.

Comment: I think this might be the word that I'll use.

Answer (score 5):

How about **ubiquitous**? It plays a very similar role to *insidious* and *pernicious* without having a negative connotation.

It doesn't fulfill "without the listener being aware of it," but then neither do *insidious* or *pernicious*.

Comment: Both *insidious* and *pernicious* have meanings relating to subtleness, and going unnoticed ( - in the case of *pernicious* -  until it's too late)

Comment: Maybe I should have looked them up in the dictionary before making assertions :D Thanks for the correction!

Answer (score 4):

***Discreet, discreetly,*** perhaps - Unobtrusive, understated; not ostentatious or eye-catching (OED)

Answer (score 3):

How about **gradual**?

The online dictionary for both insiduous and pernicious say something like

> proceeding in a gradual, subtle way...

**Gradual** is neutral and has no positive or negative implications.

Answer (score 3):

transformative -  where something changes the basis for thought patterns, not described in a negative or positive way but all-encompassing

Comment: Your answer clearly meets some of the questioner's criteria.  You have explained how the adjective 'transformative' satisfies the second and third bulleted criteria in the question, that the change is pervasive and that it has neither positive nor negative overtones.  You do not explain how your suggestion meets the first (and most important) criterion - that the process is silent and unnoticed by the speaker.  This is difficult, and you may need to refer both to a thesaurus and a dictionary.  References to this kind of research in your answer would be sure to give your answer weight.

Answer (score 2):

The use of (x) has a **background** effect on our mental processes.

This word has no connotations at all and merely states that something is not in the foreground. In this case the item is in the background of the mental processes and, thus, is not noticed in the cognitive process but is definitely present as an influence.

> Creating Unique CSS Background Effects

[SpeckyBoy.com](https://speckyboy.com/css-background-effects/)

> Background Effect Tutorial

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Idr4t0mL1ek)

Comment: not quite sure about those links

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps **non-obvious**, "not immediately apparent or such as would ordinarily be expected" (OED), would work. After all, something that is insidious is something that is evil, but not obviously so.

Answer (score 1):

[**Collateral**](https://www.google.com.br/search?q=collateral%20meaning&oq=collateral%20me&aqs=chrome.0.0j69i57j0l4.2368j1j9&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

Taken from Google's dictionary:

> additional but subordinate; secondary.
>
> "the collateral meanings of a word"

Usage in your sentences:

> The use of (x) has collateral effect on our mental processes.
>
> The use of (x) affects our mental processes collaterally.

Answer (score 1):

A word that means difficult to detect, but unlike *subtle* does not mean the effect is minor, would be:

**occult** [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/occult)

among its definitions

> Hidden from view; concealed

and

> Not accompanied by readily detectable signs or symptoms

Answer (score 0):

An appropriate word may be **underlying**:

- adj. Lying under or beneath something: underlying strata.
- adj. Basic; fundamental.
- adj. Present but not obvious; implicit: an underlying meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Arguably, attempting to assert that something that "affects the listener and the whole of their thought processes without the listener being aware of it" has no negative connotation is itself insidious and pernicious.